# push/append an Array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append

how to push/append data into this array `var tempArray = [[],[],[]]` ?

i tried to append this data

```
  tempCart[0] = (uuid as? NSArray)!  //string
  tempCart[1] = (fileName as? NSArray)! //string
  tempCart[2] = (imageData as? NSArray)! //NSData
```

But it shows 'cast from string to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fail''

**Update**
now I tried this line

```
tempCart += [[uuid],[fileName],[imageData]]
```

when i put all string in array it's went well but when i put 'imageData' it got this error 'type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Comment: Why are you trying to cast a String or NSData into an NSArray?

Comment: `tempCart[0] = [uuid]`, `tempCart[1] = [fileName]`, `tempCart[2] = [imageData]`

Comment: because, at first it shows "cannot assign value of type 'string' to type'NSArray"'. Anyway i'm updated my question please check

Comment: @vacawama thanks not the error has gone with this tempCart[0] = [uuid], tempCart[1] = [fileName], tempCart[2] = [imageData!]

Comment: try use tuple instead var tempArray = [(String, String, NSData)]()
let oneElem = (uuid, fileName, imageData)

Comment: @wm.p1us after that how to access let say fileName in tempArray[8]?

Comment: @wm.p1us already found it, `tempCart[8].1` thank you feel free to post it in answer

Comment: @AldoLazuardi thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some of variation of code for you:

```
var tempArray = [(String, String, NSData)]()
let oneElem = (uuid, fileName, imageData)
tempArray.append(oneElem)
```

...

```
tempArray[0].0 // you can access to uuid of 1st element
tempArray[8].1 // you can access to fileName of 7th element
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code use tuple instead of NSArray()

```
        var Array = [(String, String, NSData)]()
        let secondArray = (uuid, fileName, imageData)
        Array.append(secondArray)
        print(Array)
```